# Questions about teaching programming

Tags: discussion

I've asked this question:

[First common element from two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118621/first-common-element-from-two-lists)

I was looking for an answer that would be easiest to explain to a beginner programmer, not necessarily the most optimal one from a professional standpoint.

Since I'm planning to post more questions like this, I'd like to know:

1. Are questions about teaching/explaining programming generally o.k. on SO? Examples might include:

   - which sorting algoritm is easiest to explain?
   - a simple but practical example of recursion (no factorials please)
   - how to illustrate coroutines with a real-life analogy?
2. What would be the proper tag for that?
3. How to make my point clear that I'm not looking for "optimal" solutions and there's no need to discuss these?

Comment: I expect the answers for such questions would be overly subjective, without substantiations. In general, this kind of question (polling people) is not a good match to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you're trying to teach someone something, "concise and elegant" are generally *not* the most important things you should be looking for. You should be looking for "clear and easy-to-understand", which often is very different from "concise and elegant" to the uninitiated. Alternatively, you should be looking for the "idiomatic" solution, the one that uses Python idioms where possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas is right on the money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it from a general question on any site:

> which sorting algoritm is easiest to explain?

This question verges on not constructive.  Some would say selection sort is easier to explain.  Others say that insert sort is easier to explain.  I've even read an anecdote of heap sort being 'easy'.  And then there's the videos of kids doing [sorting networks](http://csunplugged.org/sorting-networks).

All of these are equally correct answers.  As such, the question itself tends to be a poor fit and could be closed as not constructive.

> a simple but practical example of recursion (no factorials please)

Tree descent, towers of hanoi, recursive strlen, recursive linked list search (is this it? no, search on the tail of this node),  [recursive division method for maze generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method).

Again, all of these are valid and correct answers and thus not constructive.

> how to illustrate coroutines with a real-life analogy?

This one *may* fare better in that there could be a 'best' explanation that does better than the other answers.

---

> What would be the proper tag for that?

The proper tag depends on the site.  If in doubt, ask in chat for the site.

---

> How to make my point clear that I'm not looking for "optimal" solutions and there's no need to discuss these?

If anything, this makes it more problematic.  If you are looking for lists of things rather than the solution to a problem (for example difficulty tracking down a bug), the stack exchange Q&A layout is not always the best way to ask the question.

If you can pose the question as something that is practical, answerable, and has the possibility of having a single correct answer.. then ask away.

There is also always chat.  Many sites have reasonably active chat rooms associated with them.  Asking 'not constructive' question is allowed (and encouraged) there.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, I noticed this... or more accurately the [education](/questions/tagged/education) and [teaching](/questions/tagged/teaching) tags. They don't feel like a good fit for Stack Overflow.

I'm not certain what you're attempting to achieve from your questions? If you're having problems coming up with these examples yourself why aren't you mentioning it? The one you've posted reads like a [gimme-teh-simples-codez](/questions/tagged/gimme-teh-simples-codez) question and the ones you're suggesting adding appear to be subjective. Asking for the "best" is unlikely to be a good fit for Stack Exchange in general.

However, I can see how something along the lines of the following would be more constructive:

> I'm trying to teach people Python; this is the problem. I need a really simple, elegant solution. Here is my current solution, but I don't think it's simple enough for reason X. How can I demonstrate a solution to this problem to my student(s) that takes reason X into account?

Comment: Incidentally; I am actively handling the education tag and its questions. One at a time!

Comment: That's going to take you a while @Andrew :-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a good fit for SO (though it's not such a poor fit that I'd flag your original question), but I  **do** believe it's a good fit for...**somewhere** on StackExchange. I'm just not sure where.

I've been struggling a bit lately with how the boundaries of each SE site are defined; recently, for instance, I [ended up putting the same question on three different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178130/218334) because I simply couldn't figure out where it belonged. I think it's finally where it belongs, but as you can see from my "final edit" of that question, the process was much more confusing than it should have been, and there doesn't seem to be any clear sense in the community of where particular questions belong.

So while I'd like to recommend a particular SE site for you, I'm not sure I can (or should, considering that my recent experience shows that I'm probably not a good judge). I'd suggest asking on the [Computer Science meta](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/) whether the question would be welcome there. If not, Programmers might be a good place for it. If neither of those sites work, you might even consider making a proposal on Area 51.

Best of luck!