# Why was this question on detecting infinite loops closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

#### FINAL EDIT

I rewrote the original question (which was not mine) and ultimately [ported it to Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11645), where it's actually doing rather well. So my final thoughts on the matter are:

- From my perspective, it was too difficult to determine where the "right" place for this question was. Multiple people suggested multiple places for it, including "just rewrite it yourself and put it back on SO" ([which was what I originally did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16250472/1858225)). At first I thought the theoretical version of the question belonged on theoretical CS, which perhaps it would have if it weren't for the existence of (non-theoretical) CS--which I didn't even know about.
- It's troubling to me that this question is only welcome on a beta site. I firmly believe that this content belongs *somewhere* on StackExchange; the CS exchange site [seems to be doing fairly well](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science), but it could still ultimately be deleted. I'm not sure why, as a community, we're so quick to reject questions like this, given that there was no clear consensus regarding where it actually belonged.

---

Original post:

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16249785/1858225) quite interesting, even though I admit that it doesn't show a **lot** of research effort. Still, it could be improved as the OP discovers more about their situation.

It was closed as not constructive with no explanation, though. While it's true that there might not be enough information presented in the question itself to determine what's actually happening, *something* is causing the behavior observed, and people observing similar behavior might want or need to know what *kinds* of things might cause it; furthermore, once we and the OP discover what's actually wrong, the cause can be posted as an answer and accepted. Just because there will be a multiplicity of answers until that happens hardly means that this question is going to " solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: There is no way to know what is actually happening, this goes against "We expect answers to be **supported by facts, references**, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or **extended discussion**."

Comment: Let's just say that the "not constructive" reason gets misinterpreted all the time (hopefully not by *some* of the users who voted to close...). This seems more like not a real question than not constructive to me.

Comment: Though the "let's throw something at a wall and see what sticks" factor is so high @BoltClock'saUnicorn, that I kind of can understand NC as well. Though I might have gone for NARQ.

Comment: Did I misinterpret the close reason? (Just want to ask so that I know). I closed as NC, since the question will invite guess work rather than real answers. I think NARQ also fits the bill, since it is too vague and there is not enough information to arrive at a solution.

Comment: If nothing else, the question of whether or not there exists an OS that can detect infinite loops--and subsequently stop the associated process--should be definitely answerable. It's probably even possible to answer whether such a thing is even theoretically possible.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Such question on its own might be answerable, but the OP's question gives the impression of asking of what actually happened for OP's case.

Comment: @nhahtdh: So...can we (by which I mean someone with the ability to cast reopen votes) edit and reopen it? I'm honestly quite bummed that it got closed right before I got to post my answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I think it depends. I will support a question that asks the problem in general, but I wouldn't edit the current question since it would change the meaning significantly if I do so (unless OP is OK with it). If you want to, you can write a new self-answer question, or blog about it.

Comment: Mkay. I don't have a personal blog (yet), so I'll do the self-answer thing.

Comment: @KyleStrand Make sure to make your question a good one though. A bad question might well see it closed, no matter if it has a perfect answer.

Comment: Here's the question. Haven't posted an answer yet. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16250472/1858225

Comment: @KyleStrand: Looks fair enough.

Comment: Thanks. Answer's up. Someone already downvoted the question, but someone else upvoted, so...yay?

Comment: If you want to rephrase your question, rephrase your original question, don't just repost it.  If it doesn't fall under the conditions for NARQ, then it can get reopen votes.

Comment: The original question wasn't mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249785/can-the-operating-system-determine-that-the-process-is-in-infinite-loop) is more of a question about how servers work: what can cause a server process to die and be restarted? Closing it as not constructive or not a real question is bogus — it shows that the close voters didn't understand the question. While the question is relevant to how to program server applications, and therefore strictly speaking on-topic, the fact that it isn't understood by a sizable part of the SO community shows that it would be better off elsewhere. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) would undoubtedly reject it as too elementary; it would fit perfectly on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). I've voted to reopen it, but if SO doesn't want it, please punt it over to U&L.

Your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250472/is-there-an-operating-system-or-other-runtime-environment-that-can-detect-infi) is a very different one. It asks specifically how to detect infinite loops. This straddles the border between programming and computer science. It wouldn't be amiss on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). I don't feel it to be off-topic enough to vote to close, but if SO doesn't want it, please punt it over to CS.

Comment: I closed it, because the OP asked the question without much information about the setup of the test server. All an answerer can do is guess what actually happened.

Comment: @nhahtdh So why didn't you leave a comment telling the OP what extra information to provide? It's obvious that 1. there is a real question there and 2. the OP doesn't know what other information is relevant.

Comment: I don't have a habit of leaving comment - since I don't want to get into argument with OP. The current question is like given some symptoms, list all possible causes. I just added a comment request for clarification, but it sounds similar to the answer below.

Comment: Punted. Thanks for your help. I've updated my question with a final edit regarding this whole process, which has been largely just aggravating. (Not your fault, but still.)

Answer (score 1):

I am down as one of the voters to close. But I voted for Off Topic.

This is not a programming question - it is is there an OS that can detect infinite loops, so I think is not an SO question.

If there was an example OS that did this then I think it is a SuperUser question - especially the original as it asks about Linux.

The more general question is rather a debate but might be answereable on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/?as=1) - or possibly [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: With respect to the question "is there an OS that can detect infinite loops," it's definitely *not* an SU question.  It's *not* a debate, it has a factual answer (which is "no," it's called "the halting problem"), and it's completely wrong for you to think that debate -> Programmers.  Programmers has similar standards with regard to questions needing to be constructive.  CS is the only alternative but I would have probably okay with it being on SO, since such a (non-existent) tool would obviously be of interest to programmers.

Comment: @djechlin: Unfortunately you can't evaluate a question for constructiveness on the basis of the *answers* that you might or might not receive. You have to evaluate the question on its own merits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see how that's relevant to my comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sometimes the OP may lack specific knowledge of what he may be asking but a domain expert will be able to provide a constructive fact based answer as he will know about specifics of the topic at hand. The question may appear as NC to others, but it will make perfect sense to a domain expert. (Not specifically referring to this question)

Comment: @AshRj: Moderation is not supposed to require domain knowledge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey *Moderator-specific duties* by and large do not require domain knowledge. Close votes do.

Comment: @Gilles: You need domain knowledge to determine whether a particular question is on-topic, but that still doesn't have anything to do with the answers (or lack thereof), or whether the question is real and constructive or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey On the contrary, determining whether a question is on-topic is usually possible without domain knowledge, but NC and NaRQ often require being familiar with the topic of the question, because otherwise you can't know whether the question provides enough information, whether the asker is facing a common problem that he can't name but that an expert would instantly recognize, whether those incomprehensible words in the question are technical jargon or gobbledygook, ...

Comment: `canihazcodes` and let's go shopping are not constructive, no matter what the subject matter is.  Half-baked, under-specified unreadable questions are easily identified, regardless of the amount of domain knowledge someone has.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The original question is nowhere near "canihazcodes" or "let's go shopping," though.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I personally don't have a problem with either question.